# How do I create (and display) a MS-Word document from a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, printing, ms-word

I am trying to decide if I can cope with the fact that Silverlight does not support printing.  One option is to create a ms-word document and then load it into word, so the user can print it.

This also have the advantage that I could use a word document as a template for the output, so letting the user control type faces etc.

How practical is this?

(I don’t know match about Siverlight yet, I am trying to decide if it is an option for the application before I start learning it in detail)

---

I hope by now that there is a good answer to this question - both when the user has word installed and when they don't.   As this question gets lots of view, there is rep to be head by a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to comment on this. Silverlight 4 supports printing and it also supports COM automation for applications installed locally.

Answer (score 2):

Three questions with the same answer... I'm doubting my usefulness at this point ;)  This product generates a Word doc for Silverlight applications:

http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Report-Sharp-Shooter-for-Silverlight.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that by asking 3 questions about different possible solutions I would get more options.

Comment: I wish there were more options.  This is a huge want for Silverlight v.next and I'm hoping to hear more about printing during PDC.